# Lucidworks Fusion - lots of apps OK?

Tags: search-engine, lucidworks

For a search engine that will be used on lots of little sites, is there any downside to having a lot of apps, and linking to generic pipeline objects?  They want to have site-specific synonyms and spelling suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "lots" you mean a few dozen then you are likely fine.  Once a cluster gets around 1000 collections, Zookeeper can't keep up with needed coordination tasks and each app will likely have several collections.

Comment: Thanks!  That does give me confidence.